# Delphi - re-build click-through transparent area after form resizing

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe4

I'm testing some specially-shaped window using VCL.

On the (border-less) main form there is a TImage which I use for making a rectangular click-through transparent area by utilizing `TForm.TransparentColor` and `TForm.TransparentColorValue`, like this:

`imgTrans.Canvas.Brush.Color := self.TransparentColorValue;
 imgTrans.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, imgTrans.ClientWidth, imgTrans.ClientHeight));`

The window's transparent area works, except that after the form's resized, the client-aligned TImage is supposed to be resized thus the transparent area is supposed to be resized too, but it did not.

I tried several approaches trying to make the transparent area resize along with its parent form, but failed, things I tried:

- After the form's resized, Reseting the parent form's `TransparentColor` property.
- After the form's resized, **manually** resizing the TImage's dimension.

I use xe4 and testing it on Win7.

Any advises? Thanks.

Comment: If you're painting the entire image the same color, then wouldn't it be easier to skip the image and just set the [form's background color](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.Color)?

Comment: @RobKennedy, Since I only want to set portion of the form to be transparent, I thought filling the entire form with the `TransparentColorValue` will also make the controls on the form to be transparent too. But obviously I was wrong :) Tried your approach and it worked, thank you very much!

Comment: That behavior is controlled by each child control's `ParentColor` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TImage.Canvas` property is directly linked to underlying Bitmap image. When you resize `TImage` control you are not actually resizing its bitmap.

```
imgTrans.Picture.Bitmap.Width := imgTrans.Width;
imgTrans.Picture.Bitmap.Height := imgTrans.Height;
```

I would also use `imgTrans.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas` instead of `imgTrans.Canvas` to make it more clear what your code is doing.

```
imgTrans.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := TransparentColorValue;
imgTrans.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, imgTrans.Width, imgTrans.Height));
```

Another simpler way would be using `TPaintBox` control instead of `TImage`. If `TPaintBox` is re-aligned than its paint method will be called and automatically to paint proper area. This way you also avoid having `TImage Bitmap` sitting in memory for the whole time.

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := TransparentColorValue;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, PaintBox1.Width, PaintBox1.Height));
end;
```

Comment: You are great! @Dalija :)

Comment: Thanks :) You can also use `TPaintBox` instead of `TImage`

Comment: Or you could skip the `TPaintBox` and use the Form's own `OnPaint` event.

Comment: Great! I'll use TPaintBox in the real program. @Remy Lebeau, I want to utilize the VCL's aligning/layout feature to make things simple. Thank you all.